# ASP.NET : GridView OnRowCommand event unusual behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am experiencing unusual behavior of GridView OnRowCommand Event. For some reason, the event is getting fired when clicking any button from the page. Is this a bug or something? I am using VS 2012.

Comment: Please add some code, your grid markup and on click event would be a good start. Better still try to replicate the problem with as little code as possible and then show that. Are you using an update panel at all?

Comment: @JonP - Thank you Jon, no need to post any code. :-) It's really weird, after restarting my computer the program seems to work as expected.